# Why Space is non-uniform and anisotropic with respect to non-inertial references frames?

Tags: cosmology, reference-frames

Why is space non-uniform and anisotropic with respect to non-inertial reference frames? Please explain with suitable examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that space is uniform/not-uniform or isotropic/anisotropic is a conventional way to state that dynamics of a test body has no bias toward a point or a direction of the space, in the absence of other bodies.

It turns out that in a non-inertial reference frame, accelerations of all the test bodies are not zero, and depend on the position with respect to the rotation axis (for rotating reference frames) and on the direction of the instantaneous acceleration (for accelerating but non-rotating non-inertial frames).